# Struts Rest Plugin URL does not work

Tags: java, json, rest, struts2

I have implemented a Rest and No Rest configuration using the Struts Rest Plugin.
But when I put the URL (http://localhost:8080/exampleRestApp/rest/institutions) throws an exception :

*WARNING: Could not find action or result: /exampleRestApp/rest/institutions
No result defined for action example.rest.InstitutionController and result index*

my configuration is:

**struts.xml**

```
<struts>
    <!-- Add addition packages and configuration here. -->
    <constant name="struts.enable.SlashesInActionNames" value="true" />
    <constant name="struts.mapper.alwaysSelectFullNamespace"
        value="false" />
    <constant name="struts.patternMatcher" value="regex" />
    <constant name="struts.multipart.saveDir" value="/tmp" />

    <!--  Rest api packages  -->
    <constant name="struts.action.extension" value="do,,json" />
    <constant name="struts.mapper.class"
        value="org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.mapper.PrefixBasedActionMapper" />     
    <constant name="struts.mapper.prefixMapping" value="/rest:rest,:struts" />
    <constant name="struts.convention.action.suffix" value="Action, Controller" />
    <constant name="struts.convention.action.mapAllMatches" value="true" />
    <constant name="struts.convention.default.parent.package" value="rest-default"/>
    <constant name="struts.convention.package.locators" value="rest"/>
    <constant name="struts.rest.namespace" value="/rest" />
    <constant name="struts.rest.defaultExtension" value="json" />

    <package name="rest" namespace="/rest" extends="rest-default">
        <action name="institutions"
      class="example.rest.InstitutionController">
        </action>
    </package>

</struts>
```

I can not identify why do I need an action result.

Comment: I would edit and rephrase the question. It is not clear if you have a problem

Comment: Post an exception stacktrace.